Normalizer and centralizer in coprime action
Let $G$ be a finite group, let $N \unlhd G$ be a $p’$-subgroup and let $P \in \operatorname{Syl}_p(G)$. I want to prove that $\mathbf{N}_N(P) = \mathbf{C}_N(P)$. This is, of course, equivalent to saying that the action of $\mathbf{N}_N(P)$ on $P$ by conjugation is trivial, but I can’t see why that should be the case. I’ve been trying many counting/orbit-stabilizer arguments, but without success. There is probably some simple argument I’m missing, but I just can’t see it…
Any help is appreciated! Thanks in advance!

You can try to prove a more general conclusion: Let $H \rtimes_{\varphi} K$ be a semidirect product, then $C_{H}(K) = N_{H}(K)$.

Does the prime " $'$ " over $p$ have a specific meaning?

@Kan't I guess it means $ p' \ne p $, or there exists a counterexample: let $G＝P＝D_8$ and let $N ＝\left \langle  s \right \rangle $.

@Kan't it means $p$ doesn’t divide the order of $N$

$[N_N(P),P] \le N \cap P = 1$.

Of course… such a simple observation and yet, I missed it… thank you, and sorry for the stupid question…
